# What is the run time library?

Tags: dll, runtime, msvcrt

Could you help with the following questions:

What is the run time library? What is the difference from the usual DLL? What there is a distinction between the different versions, for example: msvcrt.dll and msvct110.dll?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Some say a runtime library is the part that a program uses at runtime as opposed to stuff that they only use at compile time (like macro definitions).

Other people say that a runtime library is one that is linked to a program at load time dynamically, as opposed to statically at compile time, though this use is very seldom.

*shared library* or *dynamically linked library* are better terms for that.